# IIS Windows Authentication not permitting Domain Users to view site

Tags: php, authentication, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have built an internal site that has been working however now I want to disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication in IIS.

I have done so and now users get the browser popup requesting a username and password when they visit the site.

I have put the below in `web.config` to configure the site to permit Domain Users to be able to authenticate and view the site:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domain.local\*" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However even using the correct username and password of a Domain User does not work and results in the continuous popup requesting for a username and password.

The only username and password that I have managed to get it to accept is the Administrator account.

Comment: `<system.web><authorization>` only concerns ASP.NET's own security system, it does not affect IIS's own authentication settings (that's under `<system.webServer>`) and as such, it does not affect PHP websites which I assume you're talking about, as you tagged your question with PHP.

Comment: @Dai so do I just change it to `<system.webServer>` to get the login prompt to work?